Hypothesis Testing for Groups A, B, C in Certain Ratio
My question is directed to the following setup:
Suppose a researcher believes there are 3 strains (A, B, C) for a virus, and any person infected with the virus can only have one of the three strains. If they believe the ratio for this virus is 4:1:1 (that is A:B:C is 4:1:1), what are the chances that the researcher belief of a 4:1:1 strain existence ratio is accurate given that $n_A = 32$, $n_B = 5$, and $n_C = 13$ for a random sample of 50 people?
My thoughts on how to answer the question:
After reading the question, I am immediately thinking of hypothesis testing for proportions, but what I am confused about is that there are three groups and that it is asking about a specific ratio (rather than just testing to see if a difference exists between any of the groups).
I wasn't sure if

there is some test / procedure for more than 2 groups that I can do and I am at the current time completely blanking on?

or

this problem really reduces to a two group test since I can just test to see if $p_b = p_c$ (due to the 1:1 between the two)? my thought is if B:C (1:1) does not hold, then A:B:C (6:1:1) does not hold.

or

I should do three single proportion tests (e.g. $p_A = 2/3, p_B = 1/6, and p_C = 1/6$)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

$50$ is a very small number, so It will be hard to get anything solid out of this.  For instance, the $13$ seems high but, just taken on its own, it's not even $2\sigma$ off of expected (given the null belief).  So, high but hardly shocking.

Should note that your goal is unclear.  Statistics can't really tell you the probability that the null hypothesis is true...usually one asks whether, assuming the null hypothesis,  the observed results fall within some specified band about the expected results.  You haven't specified a confidence interval.  If you take a $5%$ band and just test the hypothesis that $B=C$, I think you fall just short of passing.  Though, again, the sample is so small that it's hard to trust the result.  $(6,12)$ would easily pass the test, for instance.

This is all the info I am given and what's being asked (I didn't leave anything out). I am trying to figure out the methodology because I also realize that it's not exactly the usual way of asking something like this. It seems you are of the opinion that strategy 2 is okay, in that I can reduce this to a focus on the 1:1 ratio?

This looks like a suitable chi-squared test would be appropriate (and with this data not give a significant result, though if the observations had been $320,50,130$ then it would have been significant).
